# Access files on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-10

I am creating a website and I need to display an image of the employee next to their details. The details about the employee are stored in a SQL Server database and one of the fields contains the name of the image eg **\Pictures\employeename.jpg**.

The actual location of the file is on a server and the URL to that is

**\\ServerName\Folder1\Folder2\Images\Pictures**

In my code I am concatenating the 2 parts to make the following string

**\\ServerName\Folder1\Folder2\Images\Pictures\Pictures\employeename.jpg**

I then attach that to the image.imageurl but when I run my code it just displays the AlternateText message.

I originally stored the server location in the Web.config file, but after reading on here and other sites, thought that creating a Virtual Directory on IIS was the correct option.

I have created a Virtual Directory called EmployeeImages and set its physical path to **\\ServerName\Folder1\Folder2\Images\Pictures**. But when I run my code it returns the file location for where the web application is stored.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Thanks for everyone's assistance. After some little tweaks I have managed to get it working, but only in IE and Edge. It won't work if I run it in Chrome?

Comment: The client cannot access your files. You image should be provided via your website, for example: `www.example.com/Pictures/employeename.jpg` your web app should then do the job of translating that request and returning the correct response (in this case an image file)

Comment: Try manually navigating in your browser to `\employeeimages\pictures\employeename.jpg`.  Does it work?  Or is this path wrong

Comment: can you run your app with administrator level, it might help

Comment: @musefan so  I need to create a folder to store all 6000 images under my project and then upload them to the server when i publish it?

Comment: @JayBuckman when I browse to it I get a HTTP Error 401.3 -  Unauthorized message.You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server

Comment: `Pictures\Pictures` looks wrong

Comment: @EhsanZargarErshadi I am already running it as an administrator

Comment: @DavidCleeton: No, you web application should be able to access the file directly where ever they are stored. You should probably use a HTTPHandler to process the request... [maybe this will help](http://aspalliance.com/1322)

Comment: @ADyson I know it looks wrong but I didnt set up the directory structure

Comment: Also, the service account the app pool is running under has to have authority to access remote resources (not all service accounts, even running as Administrator, have that authority.)

Comment: On the server, try going to this address `\\ServerName\Folder1\Folder2\Images\Pictures\Pictures\employeename.jpg`in File Explorer.  Do you still get a permissions error?